# Difficult mapping text to dictionary and back

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp, mapping

I have a program that has text as input.
Say,

```
I have a program that has text as input.
```

Then I drop some words and have tokens

```
program, text, as, input
```

I make windows from the resulting data

```
program, text, as
text, as, input
```

And get the number representation of data

```
12, 51, 42
51, 42, 2
```

Then I use a multilayer perceptron and have a number for all windows

```
12, 51, 42 -> 2
51, 42, 2 ->6
```

And my desire is to map the resulting number on the input data, like

```
I have a program that    has    text     as     input.
-   -  -    2   (2+6)/2   -   (2+6)/2   (2+6)/2  6
```

How did I do that? I take the values for all the tokens and calculate average

Please have a look on the problem, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What  can I do??

Comment: please help me !